# rails mongoid undefined bson_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I defined my own custom field type Price for my application. I defined all the required methods (demongoize, mongoize, ..) and it works perfectly fine retrieving the data from mongodb, sending it to front end and getting data back and store them in mongo db. My Price class stores the data as an array [value, currency] in the DB and also my front end expect the price to be delivered as a an array. All ok so far.

In my model I now added a Hash which reflects a tree structure containing objects which have a price. I was re-using the price class for these prices when creating the tree structure.

But now I get an undefined bs_type error when I try to save this hash field to the database. Looks like rails/mongoid doesnt find a method to transform the price in the Hash into a suitable mongoid format.

I tried to define as_json, to_json, to_s, ... everything on my Price model but I always get the same message: undefined bson_type for Price whenever I want to save my tree field.

(If I store my values as [value,currency] in the hash - not using Price, obviously all works fine)

Any idea?

```
class Price

def initialize(value = 0, currency = '')
  @value,@currency = value, currency
end
def mongoize
  [@value,@currency.to_s]
end

class << self
  def demongoize(object)
    if object
      cur = object[1] || ''
      Price.new(object[0], cur)
    else
      Price.new()
    end
  end
  def mongoize(object)
    case object
    when Price then object.mongoize
    when Array then Price.new(object[0], object[1]).mongoize
    else object
    end
  end

  def evolve(object)
    case object
    when Price then object.mongoize
    else object
    end
  end
end
```

I have another model:

```
class Financial
  include Mongoid::Document

  field: quote, type: Price
  field: tree, type: Hash
end
```

In my application code setting the quote and saving it works.

Here is the problem:

```
 revenue = Price.new(10,'USD')

 record = Financial.new()
 record.quote = revenue
 record.save # All works so far

 record.tree = { data: [10,'USD']}
 record.save # this works too

 record.tree = { data: revenue}
 record.save # here I get the undefined bson_type for Price error.
```

Comment: What are versions of rails/mongoid/mongo? Also it'd help to have a [mcve].

Comment: I just upgraded all to the latest versions

Comment: "latest" is not a version number. While I could go and look up the actual versions, this is extra work for me, which I absolutely don't need to do. (not saying I'd be able to answer the question if you posted the exact version numbers, but it's your duty to make the potential answerer's job as easy as possible)

Comment: Hi, I extented my initial post with some sample code. I will also retrieve the versions - but I think its not the version. It guess to serialize the hash rails/mongoid is not using the mongoize/demongoize methods.

Comment: Yes, seeing some code helps understanding the problem, but JFYI, the `Financial` model you posted, it's broken and won't even load.

Comment: "to serialize the hash rails/mongoid is not using the mongoize/demongoize methods" - apparently. I'd start exploring the stacktrace and try to see if this is relatively easily fixable.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to avoid the free-form Hash and create a formal model classes/relationships for whatever your `tree` is. Depending on your requirements, this might not be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a free-form Hash - cannot use a formal model. And yes - maybe the model doesnt load. I removed a lot of code and may have destroyed something.

Comment: I found a workaround: If I do tree = tree.as_json then I dont get the error anymore!